# std::string в условиях switch

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, switch

На хаьре читал, что в стандарте C++11 можно заюзать string в качестве условия для switch(http://habrahabr.ru/post/166201/).

Но у меня сейчас это не сработало:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s("s");

    switch(s) {
        case "s": cout<<s;
    }
}
```

---

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:10:13: error: switch quantity not an integer

     switch(s) {

             ^

main.cpp:11:14: error: could not convert '"s"' from 'const char [2]' to '<type error>'

         case "s": cout<<s;
```

Что-то изменилось?

(gcc-4.9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В статье описан грубый хак с макросами, основанный на вычислении хэш-функции. Он работает лишь для коротких строк, содержащих лишь английские символы с кодами 1-127.

По стандарту, `switch` со строками как было нельзя использовать, так и осталось.

---

Почему же switch не разрешают использовать со строками? Дело в том, что корректная проверка равенства строк — дорогостоящая операция. А идея switch как раз и состоит в том, что он вычисляется быстро — например, константы в case вполне могут быть индексами в таблице переходов (как, например, делает Java).

Например, код

```
switch (n)
{
case 1:
    printf("1");
    break;
case 2:
    printf("2");
    // fallthrough
case 3:
    printf("3");
}
```

вполне может скомпилироваться в такой псевдокод:

```
void* jumptable[] = { 0x0, &case1, &case2, &case3 };

if (n < 1 || n > 3) goto next;
goto jumptable[n];

case1:
printf("1");
goto next;

case2:
printf("2");

case3:
printf("3");

next:
```

Со строками такой трюк не пройдёт.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме switch: [Duff's Device](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0).

Comment: Вы правы!
Мой косяк...

Comment: @deterok: Тем не менее, сам вопрос интересный. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Более того, если разрешить строки, то следующим желанием будет разрешить и регулярки.

Comment: @Shamov: И [pattern matching](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/206)!

Comment: Вот, кстати, паттерн-матчинг для типов могли бы добавить совершенно спокойно. Проверка характеристик у типов прям так и просится внутрь конструкции switch/case. Там уже и default-ветка есть. И есть возможность инклюзивного объединения нескольких условий. Эта конструкция как будто создана для работы со сложными иерархиями интерфейсов.

Comment: @Shamov: Ну, в C#, как видите, собираются сделать.

Comment: "вполне может скомпилироваться..." при включенной оптимизации - точно скомпилируется. Проверял и на MSVC 2008 и на GCC 4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно ваш пример будет работать если сделать так:

```
string s = "s";

switch (s[0])
{
   case 's': ...
}
```